# Copy data from one dimensional arraylist to 2 dimensional arraylist using java

Tags: java, arraylist

Copy a row of data from a one dimensional arraylist (which keeps getting refreshed after every row is found and moved) to the corresponding row of a two dimensional arraylist?

Comment: Your task description is very vague. How are the rows arranged within the two dimensional list? How is the row in the one dimensional list associated with the proper row within the two dimensional list? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

```
List lst= new ArrayList();//considering your row
List<List> lst = new ArrayList<List>();//considering 2d list
lst.add(new ArrayList(lst));//adding row to it
```